# Program to read bytes from file and convert to hex

Tags: java, io, hex

```
import java.io.*;

public class foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    "data.dat"));

            while (input.available() > 0) {

                String hex = Integer.toHexString(input.readByte()); //I think this is where the problem is

                System.out.print(hex + ' ');

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Output-

```
ffffff89 50 4e 47 d a 1a a 0 0 0 d 49 48 44 52 0 0 0... (continues)
```

The output is mostly correct. I can't figure out where these ffffffs are coming in my output. And also single single characters are missing their 0. eg. d should be displayed as 0D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.readByte()` returns a signed byte; when the highest bit of that byte is 1, it is interpreted as a negative number, and `Integer.toString` sign-extends it to an int.

Instead of `Integer.toString`, use `String.format("%02x", input.readByte() & 0xFF)`, which will interpret the byte as unsigned and force exactly two hexadecimal digits to be used.